# I claim that there is a 'path' connecting $k$ and $1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $S=\lbrace 0,1,2,...,n\rbrace$. Define $S_0=S-\lbrace 0\rbrace$ and $S_k=S-\lbrace k\rbrace$ for some $k\in S_1$. Let $f:S_0\longrightarrow S_k$  be such that $f(i)=(k+i)$ mod $n+1$.
I claim that there is a 'path' connecting $k$ and $0$. i.e $f(k)=,...,=0$.

I have a sketchy 'proof' but I'm not sure I've done it carefully.

Example: $S=\lbrace 0,1,2,3,4\rbrace$. $S_0=\lbrace 1,2,3,4\rbrace$ and $S_3=\lbrace 0,1,2,4\rbrace$. So  $f(1)=4$, $f(2)=0$, $f(3)=1$, $f(4)=2$. The path is $f(3)=1$, $f(1)=4$, $f(4)=2$, $f(2)=0$.

Comment: I am confused... $1$ is not in $S_1$, and $k$ is not in $S_k$, so what is the set being permuted by $f$ that contains $1$ and $k$?

Comment: I may have stated it wrongly (we will see). What I have in mind is that there is a 'path' from $k\in S_1$ to $1\in S_k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of your set as the group $G=\mathbb{Z}/(n+1)$, then $f$ is (when extended to include zero) the map $f:G\to G:x\mapsto x+k$. Then $f^{i}(k) = (i+1)k$, so that $f^n(k) = 0$.

Comment: One can (sometimes) do with a smaller value for $i$.

Comment: @IhechukwuChinyere True, but that's not what you asked. If I answered your question, don't forget to upvote (and perhaps accept) my answer.

Comment: yes sure, it's cool.